# Unable to correctly run a personal job on the Beowulf cluster. Example job works fine

Tags: python, ubuntu, mpi, cluster-computing, mpich

I've recently set up a Beowulf cluster using one master node and two client nodes.  The client nodes all share the master node's `/home/mpiuser/` directory and automatically update whenever the directory is changed on the master node. I have successfully run the example compiled `cpi` file that was given when downloading MPICH2 with the following command

```
$ mpiexec -f hosts -n 3 /home/mpiuser/mpich2-1.4.1/examples/cpi
```

which gives the following output

```
Process 0 of 3 is on Master
Process 2 of 3 is on Slave2
Process 1 of 3 is on Slave1
pi is approximately 3.1415926544231318, Error is 0.0000000008333387
wall clock time = 0.001477
```

Then when I try and run a python file I created here: `/home/mpiuser/Development/fact_test.py`, using this command

```
$ mpiexec -f hosts -n 3 /home/mpiuser/Development/fact_test.py
```

I get the following errors

```
[proxy:0:0@Master] HYDU_create_process (./utils/launch/launch.c:69): execvp error on file /home/mpiuser/Development/fact_test.py (Permission denied)
[proxy:0:1@Slave1] HYDU_create_process (./utils/launch/launch.c:69): execvp error on file /home/mpiuser/Development/fact_test.py (Permission denied)
[proxy:0:2@Slave2] HYDU_create_process (./utils/launch/launch.c:69): execvp error on file /home/mpiuser/Development/fact_test.py (Permission denied)
```

Additionally, I can also correctly get the names of the master and client nodes with this input and output:

```
$ mpirun --machinefile hosts hostname
Master
Slave1
Slave2
```

I'm not quite sure where the error is coming from.  Some additional information:
MPICH2 version: 1.4.1
Python version: 3.5.2

fact_test.py:

```
import scipy as sp
import time

def factorial_func(i):
    return sp.math.factorial(i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    i = 1e5
    t0 = time.time()
    fac = factorial_func(i)
    t1 = time.time()
    print(t1-t0)
```

If you need any more information I'd be happy to provide it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you run `/home/mpiuser/Development/fact_test.py` on your login node ?

i doubt it since
- there is no magic header to use the python interpreter
- the file might not be executable

one option is to add at the very beginning of your file

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

and then

```
chmod 755 /home/mpiuser/Development/fact_test.py
```

and other option is to manually use the python interpreter, your `mpiexec` command would become

```
mpiexec -f hosts -n 3 python /home/mpiuser/Development/fact_test.py
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the problem!!